# Roots of complex function

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm a little bit lost here, how do I find the roots of this equation: $$e^z+6e^{-z}=5$$

I don't know how to approach this question, should I split $z$ in $x$ and $iy$?

Comment: First try the substitution $a = e^z$, then solve that equation.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: multiplying by $$e^{z}$$ we get
$$e^{2z}+6=5e^z$$ Setting $$t=e^z$$ you will get a quadratic equation